# Entity Framework/LINQ Error: The column prefix 'Project1' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sap-ase

I have the folling LINQ query:

```
var queryEvents = (from p in db.cl_contact_event
                   where p.time_of_contact >= beginDate && p.time_of_contact < endDate
                   group p by p.contact_list_name into g
                   select new PenRawModel
                   {
                        listName           = g.Key,
                        download           = g.Max(a => a.total_number_of_records),
                        dials              = g.Where(a => a.ov_dial_start_time != null).Count(), //This fails.
                        //dials              = g.Sum(a => a.ov_dial_start_time != null ? 1 : 0), //This works.
                        agentConnects      = g.Sum(a => a.ov_trunk_released_time != null ? 1 : 0),
                        abandons           = g.Sum(a => a.response_status == "DAC" || a.response_status == "DAD" ? 1 : 0),
                        rightPartyContacts = g.Sum(a => a.response_status == "PTP" || a.response_status == "RPC" ? 1 : 0),
                        promiseToPays      = g.Sum(a => a.response_status == "PTP" ? 1 : 0),
                        talkTime           = g.Sum(a => EntityFunctions.DiffSeconds(a.ov_call_connected_time, a.ov_trunk_released_time)) ?? 0,
                        wrapTime           = g.Sum(a => EntityFunctions.DiffSeconds(a.ov_trunk_released_time, a.record_released_time)) ?? 0
                   }
```

When run it gives me the error:

> "The column prefix 'Project1' does not match with a table name or
>   alias name used in the query. Either the table is not specified in the
>   FROM clause or it has a correlation name which must be used instead."

The reason for the failure is:

```
dials = g.Where(a => a.ov_dial_start_time != null).Count(),
```

If I replace that line of code with the commented out one below it then the query works just fine. I'd prefer to use the .Where/.Count though because it's easier for someone else to decipher and understand the intent of the code.

Can anyone help give me a clue as to why this fails and how I might possibly fix it?

**Edit-** Here is the SQL that is sent to the **Sybase database** from the failed query:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Project2].[contact_list_name] AS [contact_list_name], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C2], 
[Project2].[C10] AS [C3], 
[Project2].[C2] AS [C4], 
[Project2].[C3] AS [C5], 
[Project2].[C4] AS [C6], 
[Project2].[C5] AS [C7], 
CASE WHEN ([Project2].[C6] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Project2].[C7] END AS [C8], 
CASE WHEN ([Project2].[C8] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Project2].[C9] END AS [C9]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project1].[C4] AS [C4], 
    [Project1].[C5] AS [C5], 
    [Project1].[C6] AS [C6], 
    [Project1].[C7] AS [C7], 
    [Project1].[C8] AS [C8], 
    [Project1].[C9] AS [C9], 
    [Project1].[contact_list_name] AS [contact_list_name], 
    (SELECT 
        Count([Filter2].[A1]) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            1 AS [A1]
            FROM [mel].[cl_contact_event] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ((([Extent2].[time_of_contact] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[time_of_contact] < @p__linq__1)) AND (([Project1].[contact_list_name] = [Extent2].[contact_list_name]) OR (([Project1].[contact_list_name] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[contact_list_name] IS NULL)))) AND ([Extent2].[ov_dial_start_time] IS NOT NULL)
        )  AS [Filter2]) AS [C10]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
        [GroupBy1].[A2] AS [C2], 
        [GroupBy1].[A3] AS [C3], 
        [GroupBy1].[A4] AS [C4], 
        [GroupBy1].[A5] AS [C5], 
        [GroupBy1].[A6] AS [C6], 
        [GroupBy1].[A7] AS [C7], 
        [GroupBy1].[A8] AS [C8], 
        [GroupBy1].[A9] AS [C9], 
        [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [contact_list_name]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Filter1].[K1] AS [K1], 
            Max([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1], 
            Sum([Filter1].[A2]) AS [A2], 
            Sum([Filter1].[A3]) AS [A3], 
            Sum([Filter1].[A4]) AS [A4], 
            Sum([Filter1].[A5]) AS [A5], 
            Sum([Filter1].[A6]) AS [A6], 
            Sum([Filter1].[A7]) AS [A7], 
            Sum([Filter1].[A8]) AS [A8], 
            Sum([Filter1].[A9]) AS [A9]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent1].[contact_list_name] AS [K1], 
                [Extent1].[total_number_of_records] AS [A1], 
                CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[ov_trunk_released_time] IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [A2], 
                CASE WHEN ((N'DAC' = [Extent1].[response_status]) OR (N'DAD' = [Extent1].[response_status])) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [A3], 
                CASE WHEN ((N'PTP' = [Extent1].[response_status]) OR (N'RPC' = [Extent1].[response_status])) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [A4], 
                CASE WHEN (N'PTP' = [Extent1].[response_status]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [A5], 
                DATEDIFF (second, [Extent1].[ov_call_connected_time], [Extent1].[ov_trunk_released_time]) AS [A6], 
                DATEDIFF (second, [Extent1].[ov_call_connected_time], [Extent1].[ov_trunk_released_time]) AS [A7], 
                DATEDIFF (second, [Extent1].[ov_trunk_released_time], [Extent1].[record_released_time]) AS [A8], 
                DATEDIFF (second, [Extent1].[ov_trunk_released_time], [Extent1].[record_released_time]) AS [A9]
                FROM [mel].[cl_contact_event] AS [Extent1]
                WHERE ([Extent1].[time_of_contact] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[time_of_contact] < @p__linq__1)
            )  AS [Filter1]
            GROUP BY [K1]
        )  AS [GroupBy1]
    )  AS [Project1]
)  AS [Project2]
```

Comment: Is this Sybase? (I've seen in your other question "Sybase" in the exception). It might be important to say which DB and EF provider you are using because the problem looks like a LINQ -> SQL translation problem.

Comment: @Slauma Yes I am. I'm using the Sybase ASE provider. Specifically "Sybase.Data.ASeClient".

Comment: I've added the tags. It might be a bug in the ASE provider. It should not create SQL with errors.

Comment: yes, the problem is the transalation made by the provider:

Comment: @JotaBe In which case I'm probably boned eh?

Comment: particularly in the "(([Project1].[contact_list_name] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[contact_list_name] IS NULL))" of the Filter2 subquery. Please, remove that part and run it against Sybase using your preferred tool. If I'm right the problem is that you can only use a column from the main query (project1) to correlate with the subquery. If so, it's a problem of the Sybase provider.

Comment: @JotaBe Alright, I'll try and test this a bit. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @JotaBe It's definitely something with the translation. I did .AsEnumerable() on the set before filtering it and everything runs perfectly. If you want to adjust your post I'll accept your answer so that I can give you cred for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I will gladly do it. But, to make it really useful, we should include the exact version number of the ASE provider, Sybase Server and the EF version you're using. As this is a bug, it's good to supply this info so that other people in the future will be able to check against new versions. Or edit your question and include that info. Then I'll change it. Thanks for your comment. Maybe you can also notify the bug to Sybase support. Sometimes this kind of companies is quite reponsive.

Comment: @JotaBe I'm using EF 4.1 and the driver is from the SDK Version 15.7 ESD #02. Not entirely sure what version the server is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FULLY EDITED ANSWER**

The problem was finally in the translation from LINQ to SQL of the Sybex ASE provider:

- Entity framework 4.1 (shouldn't influence the bug)
- Sybex ASE driver for SDK 15.7 SED #02 (responsible for the failure)

The queries should be well rendered using any LINQ sintax. They could produce different queries, but they all should work. However this provider fails to do it right with some of the possible sintax.

Is good to know that:

```
dials = g.Where(a => a.ov_dial_start_time != null).Count(), // fails.
dials = g.Count(a => a.ov_dial_start_time != null), // also fails.
dials = g.Sum(a => a.ov_dial_start_time != null ? 1 : 0), // works.
```

According to OP, adding `AsEnumerable()` before the `Where()` filter also makes it work.

If you find some failure with this database and provider it's a good idea to check the query that will be sent to the server to find the offending part and try alternative sintax until the problem is solved. You can check the query that will be sent to the server using `toString()`. Then you can check the sintax, or run it directly in the server and see what is failing.

Comment: Wouldn't the .Count() make it an aggregate though?

Comment: The Count would, but, what about the Where? But that has made me remeber something: try to use a Count with a predicate as parameter: `Count(a => a.ov_dial_start_time != null)`. It's much more clear and it will quie probably work. Please, let me know if it works to modify my answer.

Comment: That actually gives the exact same error and was the first thing I tried.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, and you have access to Management Studio start the SQL profiler (by heart: Tools -> SQL Profile) to monitor the DB and see how the generated query sent to the DB looks like.

Comment: I'm connecting to Sybase and I can get the SQL generated from LINQ using .ToString(). I'll post it in a moment.

Comment: The only problem with .AsEnumerable() is that it forces the query results to be sent to the client and every action performed on that set of data afterwards also happens on the client. So it's not something you want to do unless you KNOW your dataset is gonna be small enough for the client's machine to handle.